# android run emulator with real phone

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-emulator-plugin

I saw a friend running her android application on her phone AND with the same time in emulator.
what i mean is the screen of the phone is shown in the emulator. I would like to know how to do that because this wan gives me the opportunity to show my application throw projectors.

#### you may say that this question is bad because I have to prove to you that I tried to solve the problem myself. but really I google a lot a lot a lot of times but I even couldn't know what is the name of this feature.

any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: could it be the "Android Screen Monitor"?

Comment: @njzk2 thanks for your suggestions, I will search

Comment: If your goal is to display your app on a projector screen, why not use something like [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want to achieve (show your application through projectors).

http://www.mymobiler.com/